# Grep - How to concatenate filename to each returned line of file content?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a statement which

1. Finds a set of files
2. Cats their contents out
3. Then greps their contents

It is this pipeline:

```
find . | grep -i "Test_" | xargs cat | grep -i "start-node name="
```

produces an output such as:

```
<start-node name="Start" secure="false"/>
<start-node name="Run" secure="false"/>
```

What I was hoping to get is something like:

```
filename1-<start-node name="Start" secure="false"/>
filename2-<start-node name="Run" secure="false"/>
```

Comment: Without input data, I'm having difficulry figuring out exactly what this does. Does grep's `-l` option (lower case L) not achieve what you're looking for, without the need for `find`?  Something like `grep -lr "start-node name=" .` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier may be to execute grep on the result of `find`, without `xargs` and `cat`:

```
grep -i "Test_" `find .` | grep -i "start-node name="
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution provided the file-names before the match results, which i'm able to clean up using sed.

Comment: I believe that this, like the question, suffers from the perennial [ParslingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problems. While you're not strictly parsing ls, the effect is the same.  Try: `mkdir tmp$$; cd tmp$$; echo hello > foo\ bar; grep -i hello \`find .\` `

Answer (score 0):

Because you `cat` all the files into a single stream, `grep` doesn't have any filename information.  You want to give all the filenames to `grep` as arguments:

```
find ... | xargs grep "<start-node name=" /dev/null
```

Note two additional changes - I've dropped the `-i` flag, as it appears you're inspecting XML, and that's not case-insensitive; I've added `/dev/null` to the list of files, so that `grep` always has at least two files of input, even if `find` only gives one result.  That's the portable way to get `grep` to print filenames.

Now, let's look at the `find` command.  Instead of finding all files, then filtering through `grep`, we can use the `-iregex` predicate of GNU grep:

```
find . -iregex '.*Test_.*' \( -type 'f' -o -type 'l' \) | xargs grep ...
```

The mixed-case pattern suggests your filenames aren't really case-insensitive, and you might not want to grep symlinks (I'm sure you don't want directories and special files passed through), in which case you can simplify (and can use portable `find` again):

```
find . -name '*Test_*' -type 'f' | xargs grep ...
```

Now protect against the kind of filenames that trip up pipelines, and you have

```
find . -name '*Test_*' -type 'f' -print0 \
   | xargs -0 grep -e "<start-node name=" -- /dev/null
```

Alternatively, if you have GNU grep, you don't need `find` at all:

```
grep --recursive --include '*[Tt]est_*' -e "<start-node name=" .
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to count them:

```
find . | grep -i "Test_" | xargs cat | grep -i "start-node name=" | awk 'BEGIN{n=0}{n=n+1;print "filename" n "-" $0}'
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for the filenames, so the count on its own is clearly insufficient.

Answer (score -1):

From `man grep`:

```
 -H      Always print filename headers with output lines.
```

Comment: Adding this flag would just produce '(standard input)' where I was hoping to see filenames

Comment: That's because you're `cat`ting the files.  If you pass the filename to grep, grep will know the filename.